# How to properly call releaseNetworkRequest(PendingIntent) when PendingIntent is no longer available

Tags: android, networking, android-pendingintent

I am trying to request the network, so I build the NetworkRequest and I build the PendingIntent,

```
ConnectivityManager conn_manager =  (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkRequest net_req;
        net_req = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)  //Data Network?
                .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)  //Wifi
                .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)  //This might be what need internet permission
                .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_MMS)
                .build();

        Intent intent_sent = new Intent(activity, Service_MmsNetworkAvailable.class);

        PendingIntent pending_intent_net_req_received = PendingIntent.getService(activity, 0, intent_sent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        conn_manager.requestNetwork(net_req, pending_intent_net_req_received);
```

Then once the Service runs from the PendingIntent calling it, I am doing some Network stuff inside the Service and then when I'm done I believe I need to call releaseNetworkRequest(PendingIntent).

But here's the whole problem of mine, how do I reference the PendingIntent that started the Service from inside the Service? There is no guarantee that the Activity that created the NetworkRequest and PendingIntent will still be alive so I cannot rely on returning to that Activity to be able to call releaseNetworkRequest(PendingIntent) where I have reference to the PendingIntent.

Android specifically states that you must pass in the same PendingIntent into releaseNetworkRequest(PendingIntent) that you passed into conn_manager.requestNetwork(net_req, pending_intent_net_req_received);

So how is a developer supposed to releaseNetworkRequest(PendingIntent)?

Can I somehow reference the PendingIntent from the Service? I understand that PendingIntents stay alive even after the Activity that called it parishes into the abyss.

I must be missing something here, PendingIntents call Activities, Receivers, and Services, none of which I see can reference back to the original PendingIntent.
Furthermore, NULL cannot be passed into releaseNetworkRequest(PendingIntent)
according to Android documentation?

Also just to note, I am only doing this because startUsingNetworkFeature() is deprecated and developers are encouraged to use NetworkRequest(), arg!!!

I am literally stuck here now with no way to go, this is rare to be so backed into a corner here if anyone can shed light on this predicament of mine I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recreate the `PendingIntent` in your `Service` by using the same code you used when you created it in the first place:

```
Intent intent_sent = new Intent(activity, Service_MmsNetworkAvailable.class);
PendingIntent pending_intent_net_req_received = PendingIntent.getService(activity, 0, intent_sent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Instead of `activity` in `new Intent(...)`, you can use the `Service` instance, as you just need a `Context` from your application.

NOTES:

1. It probably isn't necessary to use `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` when creating (or recreating) this `PendingIntent`. I've had a number of issues with the behaviour of `FLAG_ONE_SHOT`, so I would just remove it if I were you.
2. The documentation indicates that the `PendingIntent` should trigger a `Broadcast`, but you are using a `Service`. This may or may not work as expected. Good luck!

Comment: Ok yes I have also had problems with FLAG_ONE_SHOT. And I trigger the Service because otherwise I have to trigger a Broadcast which triggers the Service and it seems pointless ya know?                                       Here's my main confusion with what you typed about the PendingIntent:   Android documentation says that when calling releaseNetworkRequest(PendngIntent):        @param operation A PendingIntent equal (as defined by {@link Intent#filterEquals}) to the
                              PendingIntent passed to
                                {@link #requestNetwork(NetworkRequest, a

Comment: I am not good at creating comments on here so I apologize, but i am trying to make it readable for you. Anyways the documentaion says that the PendingIntent passed into releaseNetworkRequest()  must be the same, BUT..only as defined by the IntentFilter I believe. So I guess I don't understand how to look up a PendingIntent by using an IntentFilter? I am a novice at best when it comes to Intents. So therefore I think I am having a hard time making your answer fit with what I have read in the documentation which is where I got confused...I thin?

Comment: To add more, perhaps I don't understand how to recreate a PendingIntent? I do understand Context very well and I think I followed what you were saying there. Are you saying that I should create a PendingIntent inside the Service but this time use "this" as the Context? I get confused because wouldn't creating a PendingIntent anywhere in any Context simply create a new instance of a PendingIntent? I don't understand how to obtain the original instance of the PendingIntent which it seems to me Android requires?

Comment: A `PendingIntent` is just a "token" or a "pointer" to an object that is managed by the Android framework. You don't explicitly "create" a `PendingIntent`. What you do is request a `PendingIntent` from the Android framework. Android will create one if it cannot find a matching `PendingIntent`, or it will return a token that points to an existing `PendingIntent`. In your case, all you need to do is request a `PendngIntent` from Android in your `Service` using the same parameters that you used to request the `PendingIntent` from your `Activity`. Android will match the parameters against the ...

Comment: ... original `PendingIntent` and return a token that points to the original `PendingIntent`.  When you then call `releaseNetworkRequest()` with this `PendingIntent`, it will match against the original `requestNetwork()` call. Regarding the use of `Context`: when you create an `Intent` using `new Intent(context, Thing.class)`, the `Context` parameter is only used to determine the package name of your application. Therefore, you can use any valid `Context` from your application to do this. I hope this is clear.

Comment: Very clear, thanks David for your time. Also I have found a few situations where I can reliably use the FLAG_ONE_SHOT, it seems to me that some scenarios are much better fitted for it while others are hopelessly not, but anyways so I haven't given up on that FLAG yet and now I understand PendingIntents better that's for sure.